# Jenkins environment variable JOB_NAME is null

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I am passing on environment variable `JOB_NAME` to maven build from `jenkins` as below
`-DJOB_NAME=${JOB_NAME}` in build step

I am using that JOB_NAME value for referencing the folders under that particular project folder on Jenkins server. But value of this variable is null.

Could you help me out to get proper value.

Comment: try use ${env.JOB_NAME}

Comment: If you are looking to reference folders dependent on the job you may get more mileage from the WORKSPACE envvar - that'll be set to the absolute path of the job's workspace

Comment: I have tried using workspace variable.

Comment: I am using workspace as below,    "if(properties.getProperty(PropertyKeys.IS_JENKINS).equals("1")){
            System.out.println("workspace is"+System.getProperty("workspace"));
            System.out.println("mavenjobname is"+System.getProperty("mavenJobName"));
            currentDirJob=(System.getProperty("workspace"));
        } else {
            currentDirJob=currentDir;
        };
        System.out.println("currentdir is "+currentDir);" The value for IS_JENKINS I am passing is 1

Comment: But the result on jenkins build is as such  "workspace isE:\tools\jenkins\workspace\Test1
mavenjobname isTest1
currentdir is E:\\tools\\jenkins\\workspace  " value of workspace shows up the Porject name but the currentdir is not reflecting it. Am I doing some blunder over here?

Comment: I could find the bug. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

you have to set the environment handle as "env" in any external build tools you might use as Jenkins vars are not passed to the build tool automatically, for example in Ant scripts you have to set the below line before using Jenkins variables

```html
<property environment="env"/>
```

This lets Ant know that any variable followed by env. might be available from the host thats executing the Ant build and in this case being Jenkins.